# Maximo / BIRT - optional null values

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt, maximo

I'm trying to create a report in BIRT.  I've created a stored proc in SQL Server 2008 which works perfectly.  However, when I try to run the report in BIRT,  it won't run with NULL value.

```
var DepartmentValue = params["DepartmentValue"].value;
var AccountValue = params["AccountValue"].value;

sqlText = " EXEC SP_Report_ByDept '"+DepartmentValue+"','"+AccountValue+"','"+startdt+"','"+enddt+"' ";
```

Works perfectly if there is a valid AcccountValue. Any idea how to pass null value for the AccountValue?

Cheers.

Comment: Bind variables are the solution instead of creating an SQL string manually. That will solve your SQL injection security problem and the null value problem at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want to pass the string 'null' when the actual parameter is null?

```
var DepartmentValue = params["DepartmentValue"].value;
var AccountValue = params["AccountValue"].value;

if (AccountValue == null){
    AccountValue = 'null';
}

sqlText = " EXEC SP_Report_ByDept '"+DepartmentValue+"','"+AccountValue+"','"+startdt+"','"+enddt+"' ";
```

Comment: if you enable debugging in BIRT you can see the actual query that is send to the database. Please add that information to your original post.